# ICU Regex pattern for empty Java pattern

Tags: java, android, regex

```
java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("");
for (String s :p.split("abc", -1)) {
  System.out.printf("%d: %s\n", ++i, s);
}
```

returns:

```
1: 
2: a
3: b
4: c
5:
```

The ICU Regex Pattern.compile() fails with an empty pattern string -- does anyone know of a regex pattern and/or flags that functions like Java's regex?

What's weird is that Android uses ICU Regex for its java.util.regex implementation, but this test succeeds and I can't find special handling for the empty pattern case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this equivalent regex instead since ICU refuses empty patterns:

```
".{0}"
```

**Code**

```
int i=0;
java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(".{0}");
for (String s : p.split("abc", -1)) {
    System.out.printf("%d: %s\n", ++i, s);
}
```

**Output**

```
1: 
2: a
3: b
4: c
5:
```

Comment: I see from your profile you do both Java and iOS development. This question is for the [J2ObjC](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/) project, which you may find interesting.